# How to get a rolling window regression in julia

Tags: julia, linear-regression, rolling-computation

Say I have prices of a stock and I want to find the slope of the regression line in rolling manner with a given window size. How can I get it done in Julia? I want it to be really fast hence don't want to use a for loop.

Comment: A `for` loop, written correctly, will be fast in Julia. That is part of the motivation of Julia over traditional languages for data science! Nevertheless, the philosophy of "don't roll your own if someone else has" should still apply, but do not be fearful of `for` loops!

Comment: You may also want to consider the recursive least-squares algorithm (RLS) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter. Using RLS is equivalent of an exponentially decaying rolling window instead of a rectangular window. It is implemented in OnlineStats.jl, which has a lot of algorithms implemented in an online fashion
https://joshday.github.io/OnlineStats.jl/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not, in general, be worried about `for` loops in Julia, as they do not have the overhead of R or Python for loops. Thus, you only need to worry about asymptotic complexity and not the potentially large constant factor introduced by interpreter overhead.

Nevertheless, this operation can be done much more (asymptotically) efficiently with convolutions than with the naïve O(n²) slice-and-regress approach. The [DSP.jl](https://juliadsp.github.io/DSP.jl/stable/convolutions/) package provides convolution functionality. The following is an example with no intercept (it computes the rolling betas); support for an intercept should be possible by modifying the formulas.

```
using DSP

# Create some example x (signal) and y (stock prices)
# such that strength of signal goes up over time
const x = randn(100)
const y = (1:100) .* x .+ 100 .* randn(100)

# Create the rolling window
const window = Window.rect(20)

# Compute linear least squares estimate (X^T X)^-1 X^T Y
const xᵗx = conv(x .* x, window)[length(window):end-length(window)+1]
const xᵗy = conv(x .* y, window)[length(window):end-length(window)+1]
const lls = xᵗy ./ xᵗx  # desired beta

# Check result against naïve for loop
const βref = [dot(x[i:i+19], y[i:i+19]) / dot(x[i:i+19], x[i:i+19]) for i = 1:81]
@assert isapprox(βref, lls)
```

Edit to add: To support an intercept, i.e. `X = [x 1]`, so `X^T X = [dot(x, x) sum(x); sum(x) w]` where `w` is the window size, the formula for inverse of a 2D matrix can be used to get `(X^T X)^-1 = [w -sum(x); -sum(x) dot(x, x)]/(w * dot(x, x) - sum(x)^2)`. Thus, `[β, α] = [w dot(x, y) - sum(x) * sum(y), dot(x, x) * sum(y) - sum(x) * dot(x, y)] / (w * dot(x, x) - sum(x)^2)`. This can be translated to the following convolution code:

```
# Compute linear least squares estimate with intercept
const w = length(window)
const xᵗx = conv(x .* x, window)[w:end-w+1]
const xᵗy = conv(x .* y, window)[w:end-w+1]
const ᵗx = conv(x, window)[w:end-w+1]
const ᵗy = conv(y, window)[w:end-w+1]
const denom = w .* xᵗx - ᵗx .^ 2
const α = (xᵗx .* ᵗy .- ᵗx .* xᵗy) ./ denom
const β = (w .* xᵗy .- ᵗx .* ᵗy) ./ denom

# Check vs. naive solution
const ref = vcat([([x[i:i+19] ones(20)] \ y[i:i+19])' for i = 1:81]...)
@assert isapprox([β α], ref)
```

Note that, for weighted least squares with a different window shape, some minor modifications will be needed to disentangle `length(window)` and `sum(window)` which are used interchangeably in the code above.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, I could not add the package DSP. So, I tried a different approach. I have posted the answer below. Let me know if this is faster than the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont need a x variable, I created a numeric series. Using RollingFunctions Package I was able to get rolling regressions through below function.

```
using RollingFunctions
function rolling_regression(price,windowsize)
 sum_x = sum(collect(1:windowsize))
 sum_x_squared = sum(collect(1:windowsize).^2)
 sum_xy = rolling(sum,price,windowsize,collect(1:windowsize))
 sum_y = rolling(sum,price,windowsize)
 b = ((windowsize*sum_xy) - (sum_x*sum_y))/(windowsize*sum_x_squared - sum_x^2)
 c = [repeat([missing],windowsize-1);b]
end
```

Comment: This looks very reasonable to me! One tip: you do not need to `collect` the ranges before summing them. So you can write `sum(1:windowsize)`, and in fact this will be faster since there is a special method (not that this will affect overall performance, since the window size is small relative to the size of your data). Similarly, you can write `sum((1:windowsize) .^ 2)`, although there is no special method for this. Also, one can use `fill(missing, windowsize-1)` instead of `repeat([missing], ...)`.